# Select a field twice with different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, field

I need to select two fields but with different conditions, I tried this:

```
SELECT 
(select my_field from my_table where another_field=1) as column_one,
(select my_field from my_table where another_field=2) as column_two;
```

but I got this error:

`Subquery returns more than 1 row`

is there a way to make this work?

Comment: What would 'working' look like?

Comment: As it is stated it doesn't make much sense to select those as 2 columns. There is no relation defined between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its current form, you can make it work by adding `limit` clause like this:

```
SELECT 
(select my_field from my_table where another_field=1 limit 1) as column_one,
(select my_field from my_table where another_field=2 limit 1) as column_two;
```

However, logically it would not make any sense because `limit` clause without an accompanying `ORDER BY` does not guarantee specific results every time the query runs.

Answer (score 0):

it can return more than 1 row so you should use limit 1

```
SELECT (select my_field from my_table where another_field=1 limit 1) as column_one,(select my_field from my_table where another_field=2 limit 1) as column_two;
```

the query should be like this

```
 select t1.my_field as column_one,t2.my_field as column_two
from my_table as t1
left join (select my_field from my_table where another_field=2)  t2 on t1.key_field=t2.key_field
where t1.another_field=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the error message one of the subqueries is returning more than one row, so mysql cannot output the result of that subquery in a single column of a single row.

Make sure that both of these queries only return a single row as a result:

- `select my_field from my_table where another_field=1`
- `select my_field from my_table where another_field=2`